# Count Number of Words on Each Sentence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops, count

How do you count the words on each sentence if you have a bunch of sentences (a paragraph or two).

```
string = "hello world.  Hello world."

#I first split sentences into an element like so, first maybe initialized variables to count sentence, then words within the sentence
sentencecount = 0
wordcount = 0

string.split(".").each do |sentence|
  sentencecount += 1                     #track number of sentence
  sentence.(/\W+/).each do |word|
    wordcount += 1                       #to track number of word
  end

  puts "Sentence #{sentencecount} has #{wordcount} words."

end
```

Output:

```
Sentence 1 has 2 words
Sentence 2 has 5 words
```

Second line should say 2 words not 5. Any ideas? Yes two loops. Maybe there are better ways to do this but this is how I understand the program.

Comment: you have to reset `wordcount` to `0` after printing the result using `puts ..`..

Comment: BTW, what method is this `sentence.(/\W+/)` ?

Comment: sentence.split(/\W+/) typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `split` with the space character to count the words:

```
string = "hello world.  Hello world."

string.split(".").each_with_index do |sentence,index|
  puts "Sentence #{index+1} has #{sentence.split(" ").count} words."
end

# => Sentence 1 has 2 words.
# => Sentence 2 has 2 words.
```

Comment: Consider `split(/[.!?]/)`.

Answer (score 2):

Reset `wordcount` to 0 after every sentence.

```
string = "hello world.  Hello world."

#I first split sentences into an element like so, first maybe initialized variables to count sentence, then words within the sentence
sentencecount = 0
wordcount = 0

string.split(".").each do |sentence|
  wordcount = 0
  sentencecount += 1                     #track number of sentences
  sentence.split(/\w+/).each do |word|
    wordcount += 1                       #to track number of words
  end

  puts "Sentence #{sentencecount} has #{wordcount} words."

end
```

Comment: do you know why the second line of the output says
Sentence 2 has 3 words.

Comment: Because \W matches non-word characters. Use \w instead. I'll update the answer.